# Select the entire text from the following node with child nodes using xpath query in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I want to extract the content of the following node of an `a tag` with `XPath` in python. so far I manage to extract the content with no inside tag in it. the problem is, my method is not working if the following node has a child node in it. I'm using `lxml` package and here is my code:

```
from lxml.html import etree, fromstring

reference_titles = root.xpath("//table[@id='vulnrefstable']/tr/td")
for tree in reference_titles:
    a_tag = tree.xpath('a/@href')[0]
    title = tree.xpath('a/following-sibling::text()')
```

this is working for this html:

```
<tr>

    <td class="r_average">

        <a href="http://somelink.com" target="_blank" title="External url">
            http://somelink.com
        </a>
        <br/> SECUNIA 27633                     
    </td>

</tr>
```

Here the title is correctly "SECUNIA 27633" but in this html:

```
<tr>

    <td class="r_average">

        <a href="http://somelink.com" target="_blank" title="External url">
            http://somelink.com
        </a>
        <br/> SECUNIA 27633     <i>Release Date:</i> tomorrow               
    </td>

</tr>
```

The result is "`SECUNIA 27633 tomorrow`"

How can I extract "`SECUNIA 27633 Release Date: tomorrow`"?

---

**EDIT:** using `node()` instead of `text()` in `XPath` returns all the nodes in it. so I use this and create the final string with a nested `for` statement

```
title = tree.xpath('a/following-sibling::node()')
```

but I want to know is there a better way to simply extract the text content regardless of child nodes with `XPath` query

Comment: Just remove the part you don't want with regex

Comment: thanks, I used the accepted answer 8 months ago and that solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for tree in reference_titles:
    a_tag = tree.xpath('a/@href')[0]
    title = " ".join([node.strip() for node in tree.xpath('.//text()[not(parent::a)]') if node.strip()])
```